# How do I make a divider like this?

Tags: html, css

On my website I have a gradient green menu that goes from `#52b152` at the top to `#006600` at the bottom. I want to divide my menu options vertically with a proper divider like this one: http://dns.themeister.se/menu.png

The divider look like pressed into and I don't know what that "effect" is called or how you make it and that is why I'm here. Anyone know how to or know the colorcodes I need to use to make a divider like the menu on the link?

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2px width by whatever the height of your menu bar is image.  If you zoom into that image you can see it's just 2 solid colors, side-by-side.

At the end of every menu item, put that image in and you will obtain the desired effect!

Comment: But the problem is that the menu used in the image is blue and the one I'm using is green.

Comment: So can't you just change the color in the divider image? Or make your own divider image from scratch; it's not exactly complicated.

Comment: You could do this with inner containers and give the left and right borders a 1px solid colour to give the same effect.

Comment: This is a nice css visual, but i think the OP wanted to use an image to make them look inset.

Comment: He didn't mention he needed only an image-based solution; just a solution in general. See my answer for an example!

Answer (score 0):

For a pure CSS answer, you can use borders on your individual navigation elements to achieve this effect. It's great cause you can easily control the colouring, and re-use the code later on in another project:

http://jsfiddle.net/22B3C/8/

[image: CSS Menu Dividers]

Say you have a menu like:

```
<ul>
<li><span class="inset">Item</span></li>
<li><span class="inset">Item</span></li>
<li><span class="inset">Item</span></li>
</ul>
```

You can style it like so:

```
ul {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 0 0, from(#99cc33), to(#76ac17));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#99cc33 0%, #76ac17 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#99cc33 0%, #76ac17 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#99cc33 0%, #76ac17 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#99cc33 0%, #76ac17 100%); /* W3C */
    border-top: 1px solid #B5F23C;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #679314;
}

ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li span { 
    padding: 12px 24px; 
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #679314, 1px 1px 1px #B5F23C;
    display: block;
}

ul li span {
    border-left: 1px solid #99cc33;
    border-right: 1px solid #76ac17;
}
```

Comment: However, in Google Chrome it doesn't display correctly. There is a gap between `left` and `right` borders.

Comment: Fixed.. inline-block has quirks with white space.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to include the dividers as part of the background image. If your text resizes, you will be in trouble, for example. It's easy to create this effect with right and left borders on the LIs. Here's an example, suing your original image (but with the diver cut out:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iylog

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

ul {list-style: none; overflow: hidden; background: url(http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-16493171/bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; margin:0; padding: 0; display: table;}
li {float: left;}
li:not(:last-child) {border-right: 1px solid rgba(256,256,256, 0.2);}
li:not(:first-child) {border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);}
li a {line-height: 45px; display: block; color: white; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 20px;}
li a:hover, li a:focus {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(256,256,256, 0.8);}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```